# Verification of a Disproof of the Second Property of Markov Matrices Presented in Linear Algebra by Serge Lang

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, complex-numbers

(**CONTEXT**) I self-study proof-based linear algebra through the use of *Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang. And yesterday, I tried to prove a statement that was presented in page 241 of the aforementioned book as the second property of Markov matrices, but despite my effort, I failed to produce a proof. Thoroughly frustrated and now critical of the truth of the statement, I then tried to find a disproof of the statement, and I actually managed to find what seems to be a counterexample to the statement.

(**PURPOSE**) Personally, I do not think the third edition of a book as widely used as *Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang would contain such a major error. In addition, I am not proficient in proof-based mathematics, and I thus believe that it is totally possible for my supposed disproof to be erroneous; and therefore, I am desirous to ascertain the validity (or the invalidity) of my disproof of the previously mentioned result. Furthermore, if my disproof is indeed correct, then I hope that this post would benefit those who are also confused by the erratum in page 241 of *Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang.

(**REQUEST**) Hence, can you please check the validity of my disproof? In addition, if you so desire, please critique the stylistic aspect of my post. Any constructive feedback would be appreciated.

(**DEFINITION**) In his *Linear Algebra*, Serge Lang manually defines a Markov matrix as a square complex matrix such that the sum of the elements of each column is equal to 1.

(**STATEMENT**) Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ Markov matrices such that the modulus of each component of $A$ and $B$ is less than or equal to 1. And suppose that $C=AB$ . Then the modulus of each component of $C$ is also less than or equal to 1.

(**DISPROOF**) We shall let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}} & e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} & -1 \\ -e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}} & -e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\space,$$
and let
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} & 0 & 0 \\ e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}} & 0 & 0 \\ 1-\sqrt{2} & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\space,$$
and also let $C=AB$ .
Through direct computation, one can easily verify that $A$ and $B$ are both Markov matrices, and that the modulus of each component of $A$ and $B$ is indeed less than or equal to $1$; however, we have
$$\begin{aligned} \vert c_{11} \vert &= \vert A_1 \cdot B^1 \vert \\
&= \vert a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{13} \vert \\
&= \vert e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}+(-1)(1-\sqrt{2}) \vert \\ 
&= \vert 1 + 1 - 1 + \sqrt{2} \vert \\
&= \vert 1 + \sqrt{2} \vert \\
&= 1 + \sqrt{2} \ge 1\space,
\end{aligned}$$
which does seem to be a counterexample to the statement above.

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: FWIW.Your counter-example looks legit to me -but I don't have easy access to the book to check that you quoted the text's definitions accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is valid. Here is a simpler one: let $\omega$ be a complex number on the unit circle that is close to but not equal to $1$. Then $0<|1-\omega|\le1$. Now let $A=\pmatrix{\omega&1-\omega\\ 1-\omega&\omega}$ and $B=\overline{A}$, the complex conjugate of $A$. Then $c_{11}=|\omega|^2+|1-\omega|^2=1+|1-\omega|^2>1$.

(If we take $\omega=e^{i\pi/3}$, we even obtain a counterexample where *all* elements of $A$ and $B$ lie on the unit circle but $c_{11}$ lies outside the closed unit disc.)